# Laravel Valet. Showing all folders in the localhost

Tags: laravel-valet

I have a problem with Valet. I followed all instructions on the Laravel documentation and after all steps, when I tried to open *.dev, browser put me to the http://localhost.
[image: Localhost]

Comment: Looks like it might be apache serving that page rather than Caddy perhaps

Comment: @BenSwinburne, Thanks for your answer. I've disabled apache and Caddy still doesn't work.

Comment: You disabled caddy? Caddy needs to be running, but not Apache. `sudo lsof -n -i:80 | grep LISTEN` should return something like `caddy   81472 root    4u  IPv6 0xc008317fa3fbd853      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`